# Number of subrings of a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

let $p$ be a prime number; then  how many distict subrings (with unity) of cardinality $p$ does the field $F_{p^2}$ have?

1.$0$

2.$1$

3.$p$

4.$p^2$

I think it will have only one subring of cardinality $p$. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by $F_p^2$? Possibly $F_{p^2}$, denoting the field with $p^2$ elements?

Comment: its the field with $p^2$ elements..let me edit

Comment: If the subring contains $1$, then it must also contain $2,...,p-1,0$ and so there is a unique subring of size $p$

Comment: @ArtW ok, i got but what if it says without unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A subring will be a vector space over the prime field; if it has to be proper, its dimension must be $1$, since the dimension of $F_{p^2}$ over the prime field is $2$. Thus a proper subring has $p$ elements; how many choices do you have, taking into account that subrings must contain $1$?

---

Having a unity is irrelevant: a subring (not supposing it contains $1$ at the outset) of $F_{p^2}$ *must* contain the unity nonetheless (prove it).

---

For the more general problem of determining how many proper subrings are in $F_{p^k}$, prove that a subring must actually be a subfield and use the fact that the subfields of $F_{p^k}$ are one for each divisor of $k$.

Comment: there are p choices so that subring must contain 1. Sorr,y if i am wrong, it was asked in an exam

Comment: @slowbutkeenlearner No, there is only one choice: the subring must contain $1$ so also all of its multiples and there are $p$ of them.

Comment: ok i got ..Than you very much

Comment: :can I get proof for: A subring will be a vector space over the prime field.

Comment: Will this help me to prove, $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+1)$ is vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @sabeelmsk closure under sum suffices, because the prime subfield is Z/pZ

Comment: @egreg why subring will always be a vector space over prime field? Can you please prove it. Also, how does dimension of $F_{p^2} $ over prime field must be 2?  I searched this question and as it has already an answer here, so I would be really thankful if you can tell it.

Comment: @User Any ring of characteristic $p$ is a vector space over the prime subring.