# Distinct subrings of cardinality $p$ of the field $\mathbb F_{p^2} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This particular question was asked in masters entrance of a university for which I am preparing.

> Question Let $p$ be a prime number. How many distinct subrings ( with unity) of cardinality $p$ does the field $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ have?

1. $0$
2. $1$
3. $p$
4. $p^{2} $

Unfortunately, I am unable to even start this question as such kind of questions were not done during Abstract Algebra course. So, I am unable to show any attempt.

Also, this question was asked before here:
[Number of subrings of a Field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831933/number-of-subrings-of-a-field)

But I had some questions in proof of Answer, so I asked user who answered to supply the proof. But as he didn't supplied the proof, so I have no option other than asking it here.

> Question in the answer of User who answered the question in link are :
> 1.why subring will always be a vector space over prime field?

2.Can you please prove it. Also, how does dimension of $F_{p^2}$ over prime field must be 2.

> Also if someone wants to answer with a different approach, that also would be really appreciated.

But kindly  give a proof of a result which you are assuming.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb F_{p^2}$?

Comment: As long as one knows the definitions of subring and of $\Bbb F_{p^2}$, one can successfully attempt this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subring contains $1$, so it contains $2$, $3, \ldots, p-1$ so all of the subfield $\Bbb F_p$. As this subfield is a ring and has $p$ elements, that's all the subring can be. So the second answer $1$ is correct: the *unique* subring of $p$ elements is $\Bbb F_p$, the prime subfield.

Comment: Can you please tell about what you mean in 2nd line"that's all the subring can be"?

Comment: @User We've already found different $p$ elements that *have* to be in the subring, and this has exactly $p$ elements (given), so we have found all of them.

Comment: Thanks Got it .how would you prove uniqueness of the ring?

Comment: Because these $p$ elements are *forced* by $1 \in R$ and $a,b \in R \to a+b \in R$.

Comment: but Iwhy these conditions would imply uniqueness. I am sorry but I am not getting it and i really want to understand the resoning behind it . so , can you please give a it of detailed argument for it ? I shall be really thankful for your help .

Comment: @Use If I show that if $R$ is a subring then $R = \Bbb F_p$ then I've shown uniqueness.

Comment: got it thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Alright so let's take a unital subring $R$ of $\mathbb F_{p^2}$. It's unital so it contains $1$. It's $1$ so it contains $1 + 1$, $1 + 1 + 1$, ..., $p - 1$. These are $p$ elements, so since any subring must contain these, a subring of order $p$ must as well. Thus order $p$ subring must equal exactly $\{1, \dots, p\} = \mathbb F_{p} \subseteq \mathbb F_{p}$ so there is only one such subring.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be the prime field of characteristic $p$. Then $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ contains $\mathbb{F}_p$. Define the operation $$\cdot:\mathbb{F}_p\times \mathbb{F}_{p^2}\to \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$$ given by
$$(r,s)\mapsto r\cdot s=rs.$$
Then $\cdot$ makes $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$, which can be proven by restricting the ring axioms of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ when one of the elements lies in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Also, a vector space of dimension $d$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ has exactly $p^d$ elements (Why?). Since $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ is the field with $p^2$ elements, then $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}\mathbb{F}_{p^2}=2$.

Now, if $S$ is a subring of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, then $1\in S$, therefore $\mathbb{F}_p\subseteq S$ (Since $\mathbb{F}_p$ is just a cyclic group additively). The same argument which makes $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ now makes $S$ a vector subspace. Now, $S$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ which contains $\mathbb{F}_p$, so if $S$ has $p$ elements then $S$ must be $\mathbb{F}_p$.